# Is it a known issue that Qt QML function can crash an application?

Tags: qt, qml

Im developing an QT qml application that is crashing the application on a Windows machine, after running a qml function.

To illustrate that i'm going to post here an example that crashes the application, after running a function:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import AsyncWorker 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    Page {
        id: page
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: 10
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 10
            RowLayout {
                id: testRowLayout

                function bigfunction() {
                    var teste = 0
                    var arrayTeste = []
                    for(var i=0; i< 100000; i++)
                        teste +=i
                        arrayTeste.push(i)
                        for(var j=0; j<100000;j++) {
                            teste +=j
                            arrayTeste.push(j)
                            for(var z=0; z<10000; z++) {
                                teste +=z
                                arrayTeste.push(z)
                            }
                        }
                    console.log(teste)
                    spinner.running = false
                }

                BusyIndicator {
                    id: spinner
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    running: false
                }

                Button {
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    text: qsTr("Run function")
                    onClicked: {
                        spinner.running = true
                        testRowLayout.bigfunction()
                    }
                }
            }
            Item {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what can be causing this and how to fix it? Is there a way to fix without the use of threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Romhakorev said makes sense, it is never cool to have a blocked application.

But the real problem on the windows OS might be related to the 32 MinGW 32-bit compiler.

To solve this we can switch to Qt 5.12.2/3 to use MinGW 64-bit which solves this specific problem.

I posted a similar question on:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/103670/qml-is-crashing-when-the-ui-is-blocked-for-some-time-in-windows

Answer (score 4):

You are running a very long function in the GUI thread. So, your UI is freezing and Windows task manager *thinks* that your app is not responding anymore.

If you wait for the end of the function, the app will work again.

You have to run your JS function in another thread by using [WorkerScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html).

For example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500

    WorkerScript {
        id: worker
        source: "worker.mjs"
        onMessage: {
            spinner.running = !messageObject.finished
            console.log(messageObject.result)
        }
    }

    Button {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        text: qsTr("Run function")
        onClicked: {
            worker.sendMessage({});
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: spinner
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        running: false
    }
}
```

```
// worker.mjs
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message) {
    var teste = 0
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({'finished': false, 'result': teste});
    var arrayTeste = []
    for(var i=0; i< 10000; i++) {
        teste +=i
        arrayTeste.push(i)
        for(var j=0; j<10000;j++) {
            teste +=j
            arrayTeste.push(j)
            for(var z=0; z<10000; z++) {
                teste +=z
                arrayTeste.push(z)
            }
        }
    }
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({'finished': true, 'result': teste});
}
```

Comment: In conclusion there is no way for this to work on windows without a thread? In a similar case it works on Linux and Mac.

Comment: You should consider to use a thread in every case. Running a function taking time in the main thread is a bad practice in Qt: you are blocking the event loop and freezing the whole application.